# Yeoman Angular generated site deployed to Firebase hosting continuously reloads scripts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, yeoman-generator-angular, grunt-usemin, firebase-hosting

I created a test web app using the yeoman angular-generator and I deployed it to Firebase hosting. When I run the app locally, it works fine. When it is deployed, the Chrome dev console reports "WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once." When I run locally with "firebase serve", I see GET requests for the vendor and scripts js files being repeated endlessly. If I run locally with "grunt serve", this does not happen and the site runs correctly.

Here are the scripts being added to the page:

```
<!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-messages/angular-messages.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/firebase/firebase.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->

<!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/services/firebaseService.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/mainview.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/signinview.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/signinout.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/directives/signinout.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Here is the script tags that are generated from this by the grunt build task which includes the concat, uglify, minify tasks that are included by default in the angular-generator:

```
<script src="scripts/vendor.566b3c64.js"></script> 
<script src="scripts/scripts.ea0abd4c.js"></script>
```

When I use firebase to run a local server, I get the following messages repeated endlessly:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jul/2016:17:53:51 +0000] "GET /scripts/vendor.58eb8161.js?_=1468259614482 HTTP/1.1" 200 633643 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jul/2016:17:53:51 +0000] "GET /scripts/scripts.3f5216cb.js?_=1468259614483 HTTP/1.1" 200 3300 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jul/2016:17:53:52 +0000] "GET /scripts/vendor.58eb8161.js?_=1468259614484 HTTP/1.1" 200 633643 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jul/2016:17:53:52 +0000] "GET /scripts/scripts.3f5216cb.js?_=1468259614485 HTTP/1.1" 200 3300 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jul/2016:17:53:52 +0000] "GET /scripts/vendor.58eb8161.js?_=1468259614486 HTTP/1.1" 200 633643 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jul/2016:17:53:52 +0000] "GET /scripts/scripts.3f5216cb.js?_=1468259614487 HTTP/1.1" 200 3300 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jul/2016:17:53:52 +0000] "GET /scripts/vendor.58eb8161.js?_=1468259614488 HTTP/1.1" 200 633643 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jul/2016:17:53:52 +0000] "GET /scripts/scripts.3f5216cb.js?_=1468259614489 HTTP/1.1" 200 3300 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jul/2016:17:53:52 +0000] "GET /scripts/vendor.58eb8161.js?_=1468259614490 HTTP/1.1" 200 633643 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jul/2016:17:53:52 +0000] "GET /scripts/scripts.3f5216cb.js?_=1468259614491 HTTP/1.1" 200 3300 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: In your HTML snippet, `vendor.js` is never included, so I'm not sure how it would be loading repeatedly.

Comment: I edited my question to include the scripts after the grunt build task compresses everything into the vendor.js and script.js.

Comment: And I added some detail about what I am seeing when the site is deployed

Answer (score 0):

I found the source of the problem, even if I don't understand exactly what was going on. I had a custom angular directive that referenced an html file for its templateUrl. I believe that something about the folder structure that the yeoman angular generator created did not jive with how I setup the custom directive. I moved the template into a string and put it directly in the custom directive and this fixed the problem. Like I said, I don't understand why. I found this solution by starting from scratch and adding one thing at a time until I saw the problem again.